# Why the substitution |version| is not working on Sphinx

Tags: versioning, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I'm new using Sphinx to document my work. I want do add the number version and release to my documentation in PDF.

In the `conf.py` file, a version variable is defined that we can use in the `.rst` files like such:

```
|version|
```

But its not working for me, i don't know if I doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running rst2pdf? For rst2pdf to recognize the `|version|` substitution defined by Sphinx (or anything in conf.py), you must set things up as described here: http://rst2pdf.ralsina.me/handbook.html#sphinx.

Comment: To run rst2pdf use rst2pdf index2.rst -o index.pdf -s styles / ictc.style --custom-cover = cover / ictc.tmpl -e /home/jmandujano/public_html/test2/extensions/blank_toc.py -b 1

Comment: The rst2pdf.pdfbuilder extension where can I find it?

Comment: The extension is part of the rst2pdf distribution.

Comment: I set my conf.py as in the manual, but it still not working, maybe an error in the instalation?

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a substitution, you need to have it defined in the file in the format:

```
.. |Version| replace:: 1.0
```

Then use it in text:

```
 "Latest version is |Version|"
```

I typically include all substitutions in a single file that is then included in each file in project with directive:

```
.. include:: substitutions-file-name
```

Comment: The `|version|` (lowercase v) substitution is defined by default. It does not have to be defined by the user. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#substitutions.

Comment: @mzjn I read that part and that's how I'm using it but somehow it's not working, I check the conf.py file and I do not find any errors

Comment: @mzjn I get this error: (ERROR/3) Undefined substitution referenced: "version".

Comment: Probably this is caused by rstcheck, not Sphinx. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9045